# After upgrade to 1.9 configurable product options not displaying

Tags: configurable-product, upgrade, ce-1.9.1.0

I upgraded from 1.7 to 1.9, and the drop down menu to select a shirt size is not showing on the product view page. I've disabled all extensions and set the site the default theme/package, and it still does not show. I've traced it back to the following line of code in gear/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/options.phtml

```
$_options = Mage::helper('core')->decorateArray($this->getOptions())
```

Basically $this->getOptions is returning an empty array. I can't figure out why. Has anyone experienced something similar? Bundle products work, I can choose options there, its just Configurable products that are not working.

[image]

Comment: Does this work in the default theme?

Comment: Nope, added image.

Comment: It looks like you template has been modified, maybe your base theme has been modified?

Comment: Base theme hasn't been modified, I'm using the base theme, as shown in the screenshot. Also, as I also mentioned the method that fetches the options, which is theme independant, returns an empty array, also indicated in the var_dump in the screenshot. Its not a theme issue.

Comment: If you do a fresh install of Magento with your database it does the same thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out. Turns out it was an issue due to a block override in local.xml that I added for a new feature I'm working on in a different code branch, however, local.xml is ignored by Git, so the change persisted across all my branches, even my upgrade branch.

```
<blocks>
            <catalog>
                <rewrite>
<product_view_type_configurable>SITE_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Type_Configurable</product_view_type_configurable>
                </rewrite>
             </catalog>
        </blocks>
```

Comment: good job figuring it out!